# Call JavaScript function from C#

Tags: c#, javascript, asp.net, function

#### Javascript.js

```
function functionname1(arg1, arg2){content}
```

### C# file

```
public string functionname(arg)
{
    if (condition)
    {
        functionname1(arg1,arg2); // How do I call the JavaScript function from C#?
    }
}
```

Please refer the above code and suggest me the idea to call a JavaScript function from C#.

Comment: don't getting you. would you want to call js function in C# code file? or Code file function to JS?

Answer (score 13):

If you want to call JavaScript function in C#, this will help you:

```
public string functionname(arg)
{
    if (condition)
    {
        Page page = HttpContext.Current.CurrentHandler as Page;
        page.ClientScript.RegisterStartupScript(
            typeof(Page),
            "Test",
            "<script type='text/javascript'>functionname1(" + arg1 + ",'" + arg2 + "');</script>");
    }
}
```

Answer (score 8):

This may be helpful to you:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    function Showalert() {
        alert('Profile not parsed!!');
        window.parent.parent.parent.location.reload();
    }
    function ImportingDone() {
        alert('Importing done successfull.!');
        window.parent.parent.parent.location.reload();
    }
</script>

if (SelectedRowCount == 0)
{
    ScriptManager.RegisterStartupScript(this, GetType(), "displayalertmessage", "Showalert();", true);
}
else
{
    ScriptManager.RegisterStartupScript(this, GetType(), "importingdone", "ImportingDone();", true);
}
```

Answer (score 3):

#### .aspx file in header section

```
<head>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        <%=YourScript %>
        function functionname1(arg1,arg2){content}
    </script>
</head>
```

#### .cs file

```
public string YourScript = "";
public string functionname(arg)
{
    if (condition)
    {
        YourScript = "functionname1(arg1,arg2);";
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can call javascript functions from c# using [Jering.Javascript.NodeJS](https://github.com/JeringTech/Javascript.NodeJS), an open-source library by my organization:

```cs
string javascriptModule = @"
module.exports = (callback, x, y) => {  // Module must export a function that takes a callback as its first parameter
    var result = x + y; // Your javascript logic
    callback(null /* If an error occurred, provide an error object or message */, result); // Call the callback when you're done.
}";

// Invoke javascript
int result = await StaticNodeJSService.InvokeFromStringAsync<int>(javascriptModule, args: new object[] { 3, 5 });

// result == 8
Assert.Equal(8, result);
```

The library supports invoking directly from .js files as well. Say you have file `C:/My/Directory/exampleModule.js` containing:

```js
module.exports = (callback, message) => callback(null, message);
```

You can invoke the exported function:

```
string result = await StaticNodeJSService.InvokeFromFileAsync<string>("C:/My/Directory/exampleModule.js", args: new[] { "test" });

// result == "test"
Assert.Equal("test", result);
```

Answer (score 1):

you now can do it with Blazor, Check out JSInterop

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/blazor/javascript-interoperability/call-javascript-from-dotnet?view=aspnetcore-6.0