# How to call jJavascript function from code behind on button click in asp net C#?

Tags: javascript, c#, asp.net, dom-events

Here is my Javascript function:

```
<script type="text/javascript">

    function SelectionTextBox()
    {

            document.getElementById("TextBox1").select();

    }

</script>
```

Here I call the function on the button:

```
ScriptManager.RegisterClientScriptBlock(this, GetType(), "t ", "SelectionTextBox();", true);
```

I want to select text in my TextBox1 on button click but it does not work.

Comment: use focus() function

Comment: Are those controls inside another user control or a master page?

Answer (score 3):

```js
var selectButton = document.getElementById("mySelectBtn");
var textBox = document.getElementById("myTextBox");
selectButton.addEventListener('click', SelectionTextBox = function(){

textBox.focus();
textBox.select();

});
```

```html
<input type='button' id='mySelectBtn' value='Select'/>
<input type='text' id='myTextBox' value='testString'/>
```

Try use this code for handling Javascript function by Code behind (C#):

```
Page.ClientScript.RegisterStartupScript(this.GetType(),"CallMyFunction","SelectionTextBox();",true);
```

Instead:

```
ScriptManager.RegisterClientScriptBlock(this, GetType(), "t ", "SelectionTextBox();", true);
```

JavaScript should be:

```
var input = document.getElementById('myTextInput');

input.focus();
input.select();
```

Comment: @DemenyiNorbert I've edited my solution pls, check it.. you should use focus() function

Comment: @DemenyiNorbert Try this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18931936/call-javascript-function-from-c-sharp

Comment: Sorry but I tried this before I posted my question. I can`t realize what is the problem. I tried the alert() method which is worked with button but the selection does not work.

Comment: @DemenyiNorbert Here is an example which works this method:https://jsfiddle.net/5mad9dpr/   so, I've also edited my solution above

Comment: This works fine but the problem when I use onclick="Button1_Click" can`t call C# codes,  <input type='button' id='Button1' onclick="Button1_Click" />.  Therfore I would like to use  <asp:Button ID="Button1" instead of <input type='button' but this way can`t call the javascript function.

Answer (score 0):

You are getting that because your script is being executed before your controls are rendered. Just use `RegisterStartupScript` and it will work.

RegisterStartupScript will write your script just before closing the `form` tag, so you'll be safe there.

```
ScriptManager.RegisterStartupScript(this, GetType(), "t ", "SelectionTextBox();", true);
```